# Placement of shoulder in deadlift

Tags: deadlifts

Some sites say the shoulder must be [infront of barbell](https://powerliftingtechnique.com/deadlift-back-angle/), [2](https://www.artofmanliness.com/health-fitness/fitness/how-to-deadlift/#Shoulders), other's say it shoulder above barbell [eg](https://youtube.com/shorts/fi2uhHn6Uws?si=Bs_u9bMYnFUubec1). But, I personally find it it best at a slight angle when pulling the barbell. Especially when I think of the cue of "leg pressing the deadlift".

What is the actual correct placement of the shoulder? have I learned a bad habit by placing it back?

Comment: It isn’t clear what your question here is. “Am I missing something” doesn’t tell us what you’re looking for.

Comment: Well, I changed the last sentence if it helps @ThomasMarkov

Comment: You should really get away from this "perfect form" thinking. You lift, you progress your load, you get stronger. As long as it does not produce resting pain that stays for more than 2 hours after the exercise, its good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video stating that the shoulders should be over the bar is wrong.

The shoulders should be in front of the bar, because if the latissimus dorsi are contributing to the lift, then they are pulling the bar in towards the body, causing the arms to be hanging on a slight backwards angle when viewed from the side, meaning the shoulders are in front of the bar. This takes some of the load off the glutes and lower back, sharing that load over more musculature by involving the lats too. The shoulders being directly over the bar implies that the lats are not contributing at all to the exercise.

The exact position of your shoulders relative to the bar will automatically be determined by the weight of the bar and your lat strength, so you don't actually need to think about it at all, you just need to pull the bar in close to your body.

Note that this only applies when the bar is off the ground. When the bar is still on the ground, you can put your shoulders in any position at all, and the only effect of getting their positioning wrong is that when you try to pull the bar off the ground, your torso will rotate until your shoulders are in the correct position, before the bar can leave the ground.